# M2 Set permissions and groups to auto-generated files and folders

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

Every time I installed new extensions or do something that generates files and folders, it's like I lose the group, permissions, or magento generate a bad URL, like the cache and the double slash (...cache//...)
I need to execute, a lot of times, one or more of the next commands:

```
sudo chown user:www-data -R .
sudo chmod 777 var
sudo chmod 777 pub
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf generated/*
...
```

I would like to know if there is any way to force Magento always use the group www-data, and do not create the double slash into the cache folder

Answer (score 0):

Please put these permission :

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/yourproject/pub/static/
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/yourproject/pub/media/
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/yourproject/var/
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/yourproject/app/etc/
```

Comment: I put all that permissions, but when magento update the files they changed